# UnboundLocalError at /detail/1/ local variable 'post' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

I get the following error in Django:

```
UnboundLocalError at /detail/1/
local variable 'post' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/1/
Django Version: 2.2.1
```

This is where the error is being generated:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import post

def home (request) :
    context = {
        'titel': 'homepage',
        'posts': post.objects.all()
    }
    return render (request, 'site.html', context) 


def post_detail(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(post,id=post_id)
    context = {
        'title': post,
        'post': post,
    }

    return render(request, 'details.html', context)
```

Can someone explain me about this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171527/unboundlocalerror-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside post_detail function you used post as a variable name and model name. I think your model name is **Post** not post.Change to uppercase for model name.

I think this will work:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def home (request) :
  context = {
    'titel': 'homepage',
    'posts': post.objects.all()
  }
  return render (request, 'site.html', context) 


def post_detail(request, post_id):
 post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=post_id)
 context = {
    'title': post,
    'post': post,
 }

 return render(request, 'details.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model name is `post`. And you are using `post` as a variable in `post_detail` function. That's why you get an error. Change your variable name from `post` into another variable. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

problem is fixed by Change Model name from "post" to "Post"

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-post_date', )
```